# Magento Vs Custom built solution

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

We are running an online e-commerce website which is built-in PHP & MySql.Having heard about magento we are considering it as as alternative to our existing system which is built in-house. Can anybody compare a well developed custom bulit e-commerce solution in php with Magento on the following points and plus any other criteria which to be considered.

1. Speed of future developments/modifications
2. Website performance (page execution , server load etc)
3. Chances of getting stuck to the system in future and ending up changing business plans.
4. Flexibility

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Although I voted to close this question as not constructive (honestly - you cannot get a well reasoned answer for such a question, or - if you prefer that - you can get well reasons for the both options), but as a general rule I'd say that a well developed custom built solution is always better than whatever ready-made one. Just because it suits your needs and lacks functionality you don't need.

Comment: Magento lacks of functionality? You can build your own custom solution on the top of the Magento API.

Comment: I can. But I have no idea why can't I build my own custom solution without a piece of bloatware sticked to my back.

Comment: Yeah speed might be the problem.

Comment: not good to hack the thread but no generic solution can be fast as compare to the custom implementation and best example is Amazon

Answer (score 1):

1. Magento developers release stable versions every 2-3 months.
2. Magento requires some server-side knowledge of caching and mysql optimizing, because it is very large and resource-hungry.
3. Magento provides a good functionality for basic web-shop. Also there is a community and a lot of custom modules, which is very helpful.
4. System is very flexible due to modularity, with separation between core and user modules. API is quite clear and accessible.

As PHP developer I should say that Magento is very flexible system with which you are able to do what you want and how you want. But Magento layouts freak me out lol :D

Answer (score 1):

OK, though very hard to compare the things since they always need the requirement metric what is the requirements how well they fit in to the current system and how well its flexible ,how well any new platform fits in to the system ,efforts to invest to make new system running etc.

In short there can be many factors to consider before deciding anything.

Now lets come to the point of compassion

1. Custom build is requirement specific which means more centric for
   the work it has been developed.
2. Well Developed Custom solution means it should be well designed with respect to flexibility and future expansion.
3. Performance of any custom build solution is always better than any generic solution provided things have been developed with a proper design.

Now if we talk about Magento very well designed and a generic E-commerce platform with a lot of community behind it.This factor in itself give a lot of advantages.

1. Well tested platform.
2. Future perspective design.
3. Community to back you up.
4. Once system is up and well absorbed fast turnaround time.

but still you will have to analyze your existing system what it is lacking and what added benefits any other platform will provide over the existing system
since switching to new system means starting the things from new and that in itself is a big challenge.